# How to split all number types (int,oct,etc..) into single digits?

Tags: python, split, integer, octal

I'm trying to build a function where the function does this task for not just integers but for octal numbers as well.  For example,

```
def solution(S):
    number = [int(i) for i in str(S)]
    print number

solution(111025)
solution(002110)
solution(000002222)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5]
[1, 0, 9, 6]
[1, 1, 7, 0]
```

How do I make the second and third number to be [0,0,2,1,1,0] and [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2]?

Comment: Can you add a `base` argument to the function? An octal literal is indistinguishable from a decimal literal with the same value from the code's point of view (they're both `int`s or `long`s), so you need a second source of data to convey the base.

Comment: In your solution() method, What you give your input , you can treat that as a string......

Comment: @ShadowRanger IMO yours is the most sensible solution; though even with adding a base, there's still no way to achieve the 2nd and 3rd examples in the OP, without passing in another parameter for how many zeroes were used to padded the number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this, at least when passing in numbers. Suppose you called `solution(1+2)` or `solution(someFcnReturningANumber())` instead. All `solution` knows is the final resolved value of its parameter; there's no way (that I know of) for it to introspect how exactly it was called.

If you were passing in a string, on the other hand, then it's trivial to check if that's a valid string representation of a number and split that into digits.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is essentially(*) impossible.  You would have to modify the interpreter, which has already converted your code into values.  For example:

```
>>> 0x0010 is 000020 is 16  # (**)
True
>>> 0x0010 is 0x00000000000010  # (**)
True
>>> type(1) == type(01) == type(0x1) == type(int)
True
```

(*) You could distinguish if this is interpreted from a source file (e.g. `numbers.py`) by using `inspect.getsourcelines(number)`, but at this point you are really **really** headed in the wrong direction.

(**) Note that in the above we are abusing the fact that python stores singletons for the integers between `-5` and `256`, so an `is` comparison shows values are identical in internal representation (and are in fact pointers to the same value).  In real-world usage `==` is the correct comparison for potentially non-singleton values such as numbers.

Comment: Note: Using `is` tests here is somewhat misleading; the small int cache means the values you checked are indeed singletons, and in fact, testing literals on the same line means you use the same object (the byte code compiler dedups local constants). But testing `x = 1000`, `x += 1`, `x is 1001` will get `False`. You should be using equality testing, not identity testing, to avoid misleading examples.

Comment: True. I know about the `-5` to `256` magic singletons, but in this case I really wanted to use `is` because lots of things are equal (`1.0 == 1`), but `is` provides a useful measure of indistinguishability.  I will add another caveat in the answer.